# How to hidden the Play/Pause buttons in the AVPictureInPictureController?

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, avplayer

I'm using Picture in Picture feature in my application using AVPictureInPictureController,I wanted to hidden  the Play/Pause buttons in the AVPictureInPictureController but I was failed.  I think I need help now.

Comment: Apple intends the `AVPictureInPictureController` to only be initiated by a direct user action, so it makes sense to always show the play/pause buttons. I don't think there is a way to hide them, since even subclassing is not supported. Source: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avkit/avpictureinpicturecontroller

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XbhlI.jpg

Comment: But I find some apps can hidden the Play/Pause buttons by default while are showing the Picture in Picture feature.Does it use the private attribute?

Comment: @liunianhuaguoyanxi you realised how to achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    if #available(iOS 14.0, *) {
        //Hide the seekbar
        pipController?.requiresLinearPlayback = true
    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
    }
    
    //Hide the play/pause controls
    pipController?.setValue(1, forKey: "controlsStyle")
```

Comment: Hm, will this even be accepted in an App Store review? Feels like a private attribute...